# Spilled paint thinner on fiberglass bathtub and took finish and color off

Tags: repair, fiberglass

Dripped paint thinner on fiberglass / acrylic bathtub in several locations and left several “spots” ranging in size from 1” diameter to 4” diameter.

Surface is smooth and appears to have only removed the top finish surface.

Who do you call to repair?

Comment: oooooooooooooops

Comment: That's deranged. Why isn't a fiberglass tub painted in an epoxy primer (compatible since epoxy is the resin that binds fiberglass) and then LPU topcoat, which is totally immune to a paint thinner spill?   Could it be a very cheap tub?  Any chance to return it?

Comment: @Harper Can’t return it. Came with the house. I see LPU is a polyurethane. Can it be tinted and restored?

Comment: We've got folks around here that specialize in bathtub refinishing, but most of what I've seen has been not-very-durable. (Typically real estate things where it only has to look good for 3 weeks...) Do lots of research if you want to avoid heartbreak.